# C++ Singly Linked List Copy Constructor Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a deep copy constructor of a singly linked list class. It copies the head of the new list and appends elements to the end of it (by calling an append) function.

The full code is available here: https://onlinegdb.com/Hke0ev8bG

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Much appreciated!

```
class LinkedList 
{
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int *data;
        Node *next;
        Node() {
            data = NULL;
            next = NULL;
        }
        Node(int *d) {
            data = d;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };

private:
    Node *head;
    int itemCount;

public:
    LinkedList() {
        head = NULL;
        itemCount = 0;
}

//COPY CONSTRUCTOR
LinkedList(LinkedList &copy) 
{
    Node *temp = copy.head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
         append(temp->data);
         temp = temp->next;
    }
}

//ADD TO THE END OF A LIST
void append(int *d) {
    Node *tail = new Node;

    tail->data = d;
    tail->next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tail;
    }
    else {
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = head;

        while (temp->next != NULL) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = tail;
    }
    itemCount++;
}
```

The problem is that the program runs into a "Segmentation fault" at the copy constructor part.

Comment: Did you [debug it](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Why are you allocating a `Node` in the `temp` variable in `append()`? You immediately reassign `temp` to `head`, thus leaking the new `Node`.

Comment: You may find using whatever debugging software comes with your development environment helpful here. Debugging software usually stops the program as soon as the segfault occurs allowing you to gather back trace information (How did I get here?) and the values of the variables involved. A common problem in a linked list is somehow a next pointer did not get nulled, so I'd start by checking those out. Quick question though, I see the links contain a pointer to an integer. Are you certain that these pointers are to values still in scope?

Comment: The strange thing is that there was no error at all in Visual Studio. Everything was printing correctly. But when I ran it online, it stopped halfway with the error, and I couldn't understand pinpoint what was wrong even with debugging. Thanks for the debug guide.

Comment: @user1118321, thank you for pointing that out. I didn't even realize. I'll update it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `LinkedList::head` and `LinkedList::itemCount` in the copy constructor. The initialization performed in the regular constructor only applies when the regular constructor is actually used.

As a result, `LinkedList::append` sees random garbage when checking the `head` pointer, assumes it's valid and then causes a seg fault when using that invalid pointer.

Comment: [Delegating to the default constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) may be useful here.

Comment: Thank you for that! Such a silly mistake on my part. Though I wonder why I didn't get an error when running it on Visual Studio.

Comment: @Kal different allocation strategies, possibly less clutter caused by the runtime. Which means you by chance hit a memory region which wasn't written to you yet and still completely null.

Comment: Debug builds often zero memory which could hide bugs. As soon as you turn on optimizations, you can start getting garbage instead of zeros